# Kernel Module not assigning variables in llseek

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am writting a character device kernel module and am running into a very weird issue. I am setting variables to certain values, but I do not get the values back when I print them with printk(). Here is my code (with excessive printk):

```
loff_t llseek(struct file *filp, loff_t off, int whence)
{
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "In llseek\n");
printk(KERN_NOTICE "filp->f_pos = 0x%llX\n",filp->f_pos);
printk(KERN_NOTICE "off = 0x%llX\n", off);

loff_t newpos;

switch(whence) {
  case 0: /* SEEK_SET */
      printk(KERN_NOTICE "SEEK_SET\n");
      newpos = off;
      printk(KERN_NOTICE "1] newpos = 0x%X\n",newpos);
      printk(KERN_NOTICE "2] newpos = 0x%X\n",newpos);
      break;

  case 1: /* SEEK_CUR */
     newpos = filp->f_pos + off;
     printk(KERN_NOTICE "SEEK_CUR\n");
     break;

  case 2: /* SEEK_END */
      newpos = 0x1000 + off;
      printk(KERN_NOTICE "SEEK_END\n");
      break;

  default: /* can't happen */
      return -EINVAL;
}
printk(KERN_NOTICE "3] newpos = 0x%X\n",newpos);
if (newpos < 0) return -EINVAL;
printk(KERN_NOTICE "4] newpos = 0x%X\n",newpos);
filp->f_pos = newpos;
printk(KERN_NOTICE "5] newpos = 0x%lX\n", newpos);
return newpos;
}
```

This is called from userspace with this:

`lseek(dev_fd, 0x90, 0);`

Here is the console output:

```
[   53.764351] In llseek
[   53.766208] filp->f_pos = 0x0
[   53.768629] off = 0x90
[   53.770560] SEEK_SET
[   53.772341] 1] newpos = 0xC139D40C
[   53.775117] 2] newpos = 0x0
[   53.777395] 3] newpos = 0x0
[   53.779680] 4] newpos = 0x0
[   53.781959] 5] newpos = 0xC139D40C
```

I would have expected the output to be:

```
[   53.764351] In llseek
[   53.766208] filp->f_pos = 0x0
[   53.768629] off = 0x90
[   53.770560] SEEK_SET
[   53.772341] 1] newpos = 0x90
[   53.775117] 2] newpos = 0x90
[   53.777395] 3] newpos = 0x90
[   53.779680] 4] newpos = 0x90
[   53.781959] 5] newpos = 0x90
```

Why would the value of `newpos` change with two consecutive calls of printk

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you use "%X" sometimes "%lX" sometimes "%llX". Those all expect different types to be passed in the variable arguments.

With loff_t, they should probably all be "%llX"